# Swift iOS: ImageUrl in Firebase database

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

My current code for saving the user image in my storage database is:

```
            if let uploadData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.profileImage.image!)
            {


                storage.put(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in

                    if error != nil {
                        print(error!)
                        return
                    }
                    print(metadata!)
                })
            }
```

So my question here is how do I get the image url back to my firebase database? I have user information that I store in the user.uid as seen below:

```
            let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(fromURL: "https://databaseURL.firebaseio.com/")

            let userReference = ref.child("Users").child(uid)

            let values: [String : Any] = ["Full name": name, "Email": email, "Username": username]


            userReference.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in

                if err != nil {

                    return
                }

                let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

                let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Homepage") as! homepageViewController

                self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)

                //stops loading
                self.loadingIndicator.stopAnimating()
            })
```

So how do I store the image URL into this JSON that I have for each user?

Rules:

```
{

"rules":
 {

".read": "auth != null",


".write": "auth != null"
}

}
```

Comment: Please explain more about your storage object. Is it OpenStack Object Storage ?

Comment: Strongly recommend you check out Zero To App (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAsvwy1-oxE) and it's source code (https://gist.github.com/mcdonamp/cc45567cd95ba2a62017cb21e891effd)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First add FirebaseUI and SDWebImage in your podfile and install.
2. create a storage reference (see Firebase doc): https://Firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files
3. Now you can load the image directly from Firebase Storage gs URL no need to store any HTTP URL Firebase will internally do everything for you.

You can save a reference name of a particular image in the Firebase Database to identify that particular image.

**Example from Firebase doc:**

```
 // Reference to an image file in Firebase Storage
 let reference = storageRef.child("images/stars.jpg")

// UIImageView in your ViewController
let imageView: UIImageView = self.imageView

// Placeholder image
let placeholderImage = UIImage(named: "placeholder.jpg")

// Load the image using SDWebImage
imageView.sd_setImage(with: reference, placeholderImage: placeholderImage)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4.1 Simple Solution :-**

> 1. Get your Stored image full path url from :-

```
  // Create a reference from a Google Cloud Storage URI
            let gsReference = Storage.storage().reference(forURL:  "gs://<your-firebase-storage-bucket>/imageFolder/abc.jpg")
            print(gsReference.fullPath)//imageFolder/abc.jpg
            print(gsReference.bucket)//yourapp-206323.appspot.com
            print(gsReference.name)//abc.jpg
            gsReference.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                if let _url = url{
                    print(_url)
                    //use this _url in your any lazy loading third party library  and load image in your UITableViewCell
                    //in my case is user Kingfisher third party lasy loading
                      self.imgVUser.kf.setImage(with: _url)
                }
            })
```

> 2. Result in UITableViewCell :- http://g.recordit.co/Ks22unDP8x.gif.
> 3. For More Professional reference learning :- https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files

**Happy Coding !!! :)**